# How to get only the last string from cells in one column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get the last String (from the right hand side) of the cells in a column but I cant figure it out.

I have this code that would get the first three digits from the left hand side but yeah that wont work.

```
var first_3_digs = values.filter(r => {
                                                                                    if(r.toString().includes('_')){return r;}
                                                                                }).map(r=> r.toString().split('_')[0]);
```

[image]

For example if I want as an input CS_1*44u i want the output u. Same for ml, l etc...

If you need more info please let me know.

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: When your sample input situation is used, can you provide the sample output values you expect?

Comment: Provide sample input and  expected output as text. Provide your attempt at getting a solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late response

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Do you need more Information ?

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Now I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: do you think you can post another answer please?   I would really appreciate it

Comment: The answer doesn't really seem to me to be functional. I dont think there is a need for the texts variable

Comment: Why do you think the answer is not functional? It seems to accomplish what you are asking for.

Comment: Because it wont work for any text . In that case I would need to go over all the cells and write them inside the array texts in order for it to work instead of maping over the cells in the column and getting just the string part (before the index) from the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to get the 'units' from several cells:

```js
const unit = x => /[\d]+[\D]+/.test(x) ? x.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] : '';

var texts = ['CS_1*44u', 'Case', '72x64ml', '11x37kg', '123'];

texts.forEach(x => console.log(unit(x))); // --> 'u', '', 'ml', 'kg', ''
```

Example how to get the 'unit' from one cell:

```js
const unit = x => /[\d]+[\D]+/.test(x) ? x.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] : '';

var cell_value = 'CS_1*44u';

console.log(unit(cell_value)); // --> 'u'
```

If you need to get the array of the 'units' from another array of cells you can map the function this way:

```js
const unit = x => /[\d]+[\D]+/.test(x) ? x.match(/[A-z]+$/)[0] : '';

var cells = ['CS_1*44u', 'Case', '72x64ml', '11x37kg', '123'];

var units = cells.map(x => unit(x)); // <---- here

console.log(units); // --> ['u', '', 'ml', 'kg', '']
```

Comment: In that case I would need to go over all the cells and write them inside the array texts in order for it to work instead of maping over the cells in the column and getting just the string part (before the index) from the cell . DO you think you can write a code that would work that way?

Comment: I've added the example how you can get the array of units from the array of cells.

Answer (score 1):

as you have tagged formulas for possible solution, i will offer the following REGEXEXTRACT formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K1,"[^(\d+(\.\d+)?)(?!.*\d+(\.\d+)?)]*$")
```

explanation:

AFTER last occurrence of "a":

```
[^a]*$
```

LAST digit (with or without decimal):

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?)(?!.*\d+(\.\d+)?)
```

[image]

**[EDIT]**

where `\d` means a number, here is a (shorter) alternative which is also tested as working with the same dataset:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(K1,"[^\d]*$")
```